# What is the best practice for handling CSS margin/padding "conflicts"?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>`, with `padding{0.5em}`.  Inside that are a bunch of `<label>`s with form fields etc in them, set to `display:block;margin:0 0 0.8em`, to give a bit of space between them.

The problem is that the bottom of my div then ends up with an effective padding-bottom of 1.3em.

What's the best solution to this?

I can set the div's padding to `0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em` to "improve" the problem from 1.3em to 0.8em, but it's still not the 0.5em that it should be.  Negative padding values aren't allowed.

I can obviously use a `:last-child` pseudoselector to give a `margin-bottom` of 0 on the last label tag, but I feel there must be a neater/easier/more maintainable way?

I could set `margin:0.4em 0` and `padding:0.1em 0.5em`, but it seems messy, and breaks down as soon as I want to add (for example) an `<h2>` at the top of the div.

Ideally I'd like for the first top and last bottom margin on the child elements to be set to "collapse", somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: please add a fiddle to check your question in action

Answer (score 5):

The way I'd do it is to add a `margin-top` on any label following another element/selector in the markup, instead of `margin-bottom` on all of them.

For example, if you have alternating `<label>` and `<input>` elements:

```
<div>
  <label>
  <input>

  <label>
  <input>
</div>
```

...then I'd use a adjacent sibling selector to target only labels following inputs, thus ignoring the first input:

```
input + label {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
}
```

That said, if the markup doesn't allow that pattern, `:last-child` (or even better, `:last-of-type`) would be fine.

Comment: I don't like it, and I feel there should be a better way.  But 35 views and only one answer suggest there's no magic trick, which is a shame, and feels like a shortcoming of the spec.  "overflow:absorbedgemargins" on the parent, or something along those lines.